# php Server - 500 error message on new files

Tags: php

since about 3 or 4 months, I have the following problem, and I wanted to ask my server provider. It is a php server. But they will probably tell me that it is my mistake so I try here first.

When I copy and paste an existing php file, or create a new php file , by the way only php files, and then try to look at it on my browser, I get the following error:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
> Please contact the server administrator at ... to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

When I change existing file, then there is NO problem. I usually use a file editor like Notepad qq, but the file manager of the php server gives me the same problem.

Could the problem be in the `.ftpaccess` or `.htaccess` file? But why only the new files have a problem? Should I contact my php server administrator?

The error log shows:

> [Mon Oct 01 20:15:34.375940 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 33844] [client ...:0] AH01215: suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details: /home/luedi/www/design/20181001/index.php, referer: ...

What is suexec? Where is the log? I don't use CGI, I think. I don't even know what it is.

Any idea what my problem is? Thanks ...

Comment: Show us the code causing the 500, and highlight the line

Comment: Any code with the file extension .php. ANY CODE! Even the word "TESTING" without php or html tags.

Comment: It is most likely a problem with file ownership/permissions. The system user you are using to upload your new files with, is likely a different one than the one who owns the already existing files.

Comment: The "old" folders have 705 and the "new" folders have "777" permissions. After changing it, It started working. The "old" files have "604" and the new files have "644". The difference in the files seems to be no problem. Can I preset the new folder creation to "705" and the file creation to "604" by default?

Comment: No, the new files also have "777" permission. Anyway, I know what the problem is. To set the default would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your setup, OS etc I would **guess** that the issue might be permissions/ownership when you upload the file. Which might be changed after you edit the file.

Upload the file and check the ownership and permissions. Then edit the file and do the same again and check if it has changed.

**suEXEC** feature provides users of the Apache HTTP Server the ability to run CGI and SSI programs under user IDs different from the user ID of the calling web server. Normally, when a CGI or SSI program executes, it runs as the same user who is running the web server. Continue reading here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html